# Jquery in Jhipster Angular app

Tags: jquery, jhipster, yarnpkg, adminlte

I have a Jhipster gateway app. I was trying to add AdminLTE component code to this app. For this I tried to copy code step by step to app.module.ts and copied the other files too..I could resolve all the other dependencies. 
there is one component called, "admin-dashboard1.component.ts" it has imports like

```
import { } from 'jquery';
import { } from 'morris.js';
```

for which yarn compiler yarn webpack:build is complaining.

I varified that, "jquery": "3.2.1",is added in package.json. under dependencies 
How should I make Jquery available for this component.

yarn error:

```
TS2304: Cannot find name 'JQuery'.
 TS2304: Cannot find name 'Morris'.
```

Comment: updated with yarn error

Comment: I don't know AdminLTE but their docs say Bootstrap 3, how are you going to make it work with JHipster which uses Bootstrap 4? Also your import syntax seems wrong for Typescript, have you checked that these modules exist with this path in your node_modules folder?